# How to fix Windows 2008 R2 default profile?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, profile

For some reason the default profile on Windows 2008 R2 Remote Desktop Services got broken in terms that when new profile is created when first starting Microsoft Outlook it's trying to use profile of some person that's not related to the person's profile. If I go to Control Panel and delete the Outlook's profile it starts working without problem. So basically it's only Outlook on default profile that seems to "a bit broken" (as far as I can see). Is there a way to recreate default profile just like it would be newly installed?

Copy from other server, some nice little trick?

Comment: Did you customize the Default User profile?

Comment: Well i think i tried to play with it in the beginning by copying over the user profile (just after I set things up - it was year+ ago) but since things didn't work as in old times I didn't restore things as I didn't notice any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to fix the mail profile?

Navigate to Control Panel and then click the "Mail" icon. From there do "Show Profiles" and what I would do is click "Add...". Create a new profile with the information to your mail server and then click "Always use this profile" and select the new profile from the drop down menu.

Comment: No I'm trying to fix default-profile of Windows. I know how to handle already user-used profile. When first time user logins to Windows a default-profile data is used to create that profile. Since the profile is messed up it always ends up in me having to fix it by hand.

Answer (score 0):

[The default profile location](http://blog.stealthpuppy.com/windows/profile-changes-in-windows-vistalonghorn-server/) is ..\Users\Default\

I suggest you log on to the machine with a new user (let's call him MadBoy), make changes you wish to appear in all *newly* generated profiles, then copy the entire contents of the ..\users\MadBoy\ folder to ..\Users\Default.  BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP.  TEST TEST TEST.

Comment: This method isn't supported in Vista, 7, W2K8, or W2K8R2. Here are 2 articles detailing the supported method: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289 and http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/10/29/configuring-default-user-settings-full-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx